# Interactive BigQuery query execution occasionally jumps from seconds to 5 - 6 hours

Tags: google-bigquery

We're running about 50k BigQuery interactive queries daily that generally complete within 10 second range. Occasionally though a handful of queries (some days none, some 4, some in the tens) run for 5+ hours or fail just before the 6 hour mark. Retrying such jobs generally have the same SQL complete within the expected 10 second range.
When this happens, this handful of jobs that take hours tend to have been started around the same time.

Yesterday there was just one such case (job id below), started at 22:07:10 EST, and ran for 5 hours and 34 minutes and was marked with the SUCCESS state.

The explanation for the 5+ hour job execution seems to indicate the writing slowed down:

[image]

vs the later run 6 second job:

[image]

Questions:

- Given a long running BigQuery job, how do I determine whether the problem is in our SQL vs this is a BigQuery infrastructure issue (e.g. ran out of slots?). Preferably, we should automate the process of determining this: Manually rerunning the SQL is time intensive and doesn't scale. If the number of long running jobs increases over time, could this be indicative of a BigQuery outage?
- Is there a way to look at the plan numbers and somehow explain the 5+ hour job execution time?
- Any suggestions to possible strategies to cope with these type of job run lengths? Currently we give up waiting for a job after an hour and retry, which usually works (although this is acceptable for jobs that are not run from our UI but if customers are waiting for results this is problematic (hence we use interactive type BQ jobs).

Job id:

triggeredmail:IFA3ptmVpVF2n6b8L7QIPYPxlQJrAuVflVIvJPJRUUODBzR2S0bRxgzTSGg28weslHyiYf4vIqIQ7iswzqMQaIuBxvrYtlccRE96eaRFBLvJsBTeW5Ar3IsZpS5C64VTucU_0v2rMxCQjypzUCFPqzE5nq7oRXOQrl8Nk3cvrjZ6qLD7FTOeeNt4Chf__aykOZIzxzoadffVGMS7ZrDaRT7ju5ZtYaWTEcBFspVuGH2t9ERaJagazdJhxAXmYiIH

We have a dedicated pool of 2000 slots for our org.

Comment: Not the official answer, but 2 things I noticed: 1) Can you declare your own timeout, and re-try the query after x seconds? (retry with exponential backoffs because reasons). 2) Thanks for including a job id! But... that doesn't look like a job id. They are more like 'project:bquijob_422be56_15fcd2dc058'

Comment: Sorry, I updated the job id (it missed the project id that bq show tags on based on current project settings). Not sure what you're asking for in terms of timeout declaration, but we submit the job, then ask for the status of the job at exponential intervals, up to 1 hour (we assume that if a 10 sec job doesn't complete in that time, it probably won't at all). At this point we submit a new job with the same SQL.